# XOR Encryption with "Padded Key"

Tags: security, encryption, random, xor

I read that XOR encryption can be considered very safe as long as two conditions are fulfilled.
 1. The length of the *key* is as long (or longer) than the *data*
 2. The *key* is not following a notable pattern (i.e. it's a random jumble of characters)

In that case, how about this: Before the XOR operations you use the (short) *key* to generate a *seed* for a *Random Number Generator*. You then use this *Generator* to create characters which are added to the end of your key until it's as long as the *data* you want to encrypt.
Then you use this new *key* to XOR the *data*.

I have tested this and it does seem to have no problem working as intended (it can encrypt and decrypt without corruption of the *data*).
My question is how "secure" such an encryption would be. Anyone have an estimate of how hard it'd be to break/decrypt that *data*?

Comment: Congrats, you're reinvented the stream cipher. It is as secure and as fast as the Pseudo Random Number Generator you're using. Using a dedicated stream cipher or block cipher in counter mode will likely be faster. Be warned that PRNG's have primarily be build with providing randomness in mind; if functionality changes you may not be able to decrypt.

Comment: If you just use a garden-variety RNG then this isn't very secure and you have just rediscovered a bad idea that others have come up with in the past. If you use a cryptographically secure RNG then this is a reasonably secure stream cipher. There is a vast literature on stream ciphers. The question itself is somewhat off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: [Here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/10422/31720) is a nice discussion of what is a virtual duplicate of your question (from [crypto.se], which is probably a better venue for such questions).

Comment: ["Schneier's Law"](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2011/04/schneiers_law.html): "*Anyone, from the most clueless amateur to the best cryptographer, can create an algorithm that he himself can't break.*" Better to use AES in CTR mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have said, your idea is a stream cipher.  It fails to be completely secure, like a [One Time Pad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad) is provably secure, because of the first condition you state:

1. The length of the key is as long (or longer) than the data

You are using a "short key" to seed your RNG.  That is a weakness, because that "short key" is the cryptographic key for the whole system.  If an attacker knows the short key, she can plug it into a copy of the RNG, generate the entire keystream and decrypt the message.  If the key is too short she can try every possible key and eventually decrypt the message -- a brute force attack.

You are right that this avoids the problems with the OTP, but in so doing it loses the absolute security.  There are secure stream ciphers, see [eSTREAM](http://www.ecrypt.eu.org/stream/) for some examples, or else a block cipher running in counter mode is effectively a stream cipher.

Your idea is a reasonable one, but it has been thought of before.  Sorry.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. The links you (and others) have provided shows very clearly what the issues with *stream ciphers* are. I think it's going to be good enough for what I'm going to use it for though (I'm making a game and intend to use it to encrypt save files since if I didn't someone could just open it like a text file and edit it freely to cheat, and it's not a game I will sell but rather a free one so a bit of weakness is OK). Also, I never even dreamt of this not having been thought of before, since it's so simple. That's why I asked for advice from those more experienced =)

Comment: [RC4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC4) is a fast, very easy to program and not completely secure (it is obsolescent) stream cipher.  That might be the kind of thing you need.